# Numbered boxes to "List of Boxes" in Optex

Tags: table-of-contents, boxes, frame, optex

I'm trying to make a "List of Boxes" in Optex like the one offered by `tcolorbox`. I used two tricks for "round frames" and "new list of X" and "new caption" from the manual. But it seems that when I use caption I must add `\vskip 0pt` When I'm using it inside the `\roundframe`. Is there a better way to implement this?

```
\fontfam[Heros]

\ptlang

\hyperlinks \Green \Blue


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newdimen\corners  \newtoks\roundframeparams
\def\parstrut{\par\kern-\prevdepth\kern\dp\strutbox}
\def\twobox#1#2#3#4{%
   \vbox{%
      \setbox0=\vbox{\fmtfirst{#2}}%
      \hbox{\rlap{#1\vrule height\ht0 depth\dp0 width\wd0}\box0}
      \setbox0=\vbox{\fmtsecond{#4}}%
      \betweenfirstsecond \nointerlineskip
      \hbox{\rlap{#3\vrule height\ht0 depth\dp0 width\wd0}\box0}
   }%
}
\def\roundframe#1#2{{%
   \the\roundframeparams \roundness=\corners
   \setbox0=\twobox\titlecolor{#1}%<<<<
   \bodycolor{#2}%<<<<
   \setbox1=\vbox to\dimexpr\ht0-2\corners{}\wd1=\dimexpr\wd0-2\corners\relax
   \hbox{\ifx\bgoval\undefined \else \raise\corners\rlap{\bgoval}\fi
         \clipinoval .5\wd0 .5\ht0 \wd0 \ht0 {\box0}}%
}}

\def\fmtfirst  #1{\kern2pt\noindent\strut\White\bf #1\parstrut\kern1pt}
\def\fmtsecond #1{\kern3pt\noindent\strut\Black\rm #1\parstrut\kern1pt}
\def\betweenfirstsecond {\Yellow\hrule height2pt}
\roundframeparams {\hsize=6cm \leftskip=3mm \rightskip=3mm \corners=3mm
   \parindent=0pt \let\titlecolor=\Blue \let\bodycolor=\LightGrey
}
\def\bgoval{\inoval[\roundness=\corners \shadow=Y \lwidth=0pt]{\box1}}


%\url{http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html\#roundframe}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% QUADROS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Frame titles without adding to "list" work fine:
%\newcount\quadro %\quadro=0

%\def\tituloquadro{\global\advance\quadro by 1 {\bf Quadro~\_othe\_chapnum.\_othe\_secnum.\the\quadro:}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\let\_printcaptionq = \_printcaptionf \let\_everycaptionq = \_everycaptionf
\newcount\_qnum \addto\_chapx {\_qnum=0 }
\def\_theqnum {\_othe\_chapnum.\_othe\_secnum.\_the\_qnum}
\sdef{_mt:q:en}{Box} \sdef{_mt:q:pt}{Quadro} % + your language...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#lot%%%%%%%

\_refdecl{%
\_def\lotlist{} \_def\loflist{}^^J
\_def\Xtab#1#2#3{\_addto\lotlist{\lline{#1}{#2}{#3}}\_ea\_addto\_ea\lotlist\_ea{\_currpage}}^^J
\_def\Xqua#1#2#3{\_addto\loqlist{\lline{#1}{#2}{#3}}\_ea\_addto\_ea\loqlist\_ea{\_currpage}}^^J
\_def\Xfig#1#2#3{\_addto\loflist{\lline{#1}{#2}{#3}}\_ea\_addto\_ea\loflist\_ea{\_currpage}}
}
\def\captionT [#1]#2{\caption/t[#1]\_ewref\Xtab{{#1}{\_thetnum}{#2}}\ignorespaces}
\def\captionF [#1]#2{\caption/f[#1]\_ewref\Xfig{{#1}{\_thefnum}{#2}}\ignorespaces}
\def\captionQ [#1]#2{\caption/q[#1]\_ewref\Xqua{{#1}{\_theqnum}{#2}}\ignorespaces}

\def\lline#1#2#3#4#5{\line{\hskip2em\llap{\bf \ref[#1] } #3 \_tocdotfill\ \_ilink[pg:#4]{#5}}}

\def\makell#1{\par
   \ifx\lotlist\undefined \opwarning{\noexpand#1 empty, try to run TeX again}
   \else #1\fi
}
\def\makeLOF{\makell\loflist}
\def\makeLOT{\makell\lotlist}
\def\makeLOQ{\makell\loqlist}


\nonum \notoc \sec Lista de Quadros

\makeLOQ

\nonum \notoc \sec Lista de Figuras

\makeLOF

\captionF[figura] {Uma para lista.} Uma figura.

\captionQ[quadro1] {Uma para lista de quadros} Um quadro.



\roundframe  {\captionQ[quadro2] {Outro para lista de quadros} Um quadro.\vskip 0pt}
            {Text dgd adhkd had dsglj dagjadg fsj csgsd
             gs sgls fsglfs gfsl fglf gfs rtyr rire wrurey.}


\_theqnum

O Quadro \ref[quadro2] está na página \pgref[quadro2].


\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in OpTeX version 1.08 (last CTAN release on August 2022) you have to finalize the caption text by empty line or by `\_par`. Your workaround `\vskip0pt` does the same because TeX emits `\_par` before `\vskip` in horizontal mode.

I have solved this problem on October 19 in this [commit](https://github.com/olsak/OpTeX/commit/b2a1277a243d8a9efb944796382f9fd21e8bd0c8). Now, you need not to put `\_par` at the end of caption text, so your problem is solved. The mentioned commit is not a part of the last CTAN release, but it will during about two weeks.

(off topic) In order to run your code without errors I did following corrections:

```
\_def\lotlist{} \_def\loflist{}^^J
```

->

```
\_def\lotlist{} \_def\loflist{} \_def\loqlist{}^^J
```

and

```
\ifx\lotlist\undefined \opwarning{\noexpand#1 empty, try to run TeX again}
```

->

```
\ifx#1\undefined \opwarning{\noexpand#1 empty, try to run TeX again}
```

Comment: As a follow-up: what if I want to add, e.g., the word "Figure" before its number in the List of Figures, like: *"Figure 1 -- XXXX .............. 4"* ?